# How to render a partial in sinatra view (haml in haml)?

Tags: ruby, view, sinatra, haml

I have a simple sinatra app that uses haml and sass for the views. One of the views (located in the views folder) is a partial for my navigation menu. I am trying to render it from index.haml but I get the following error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

I am trying to render it with the following lines in index.haml

```
.navigation
  = render :partial => "nav"
```

Comment: If you want more answers I suggest to add `ruby` to tags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT: !!! OUTDATED !!!** Read [Jason's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7745/jason) answer below!

What are you trying works in `rails`! `Sinatra` has no `partial` method. An implementation of `partial` on `Sinatra` looks like  [this (source gist)](http://gist.github.com/119874) from github:

```
module Haml
  module Helpers
    def partial(template, *args)
      template_array = template.to_s.split('/')
      template = template_array[0..-2].join('/') + "/_#{template_array[-1]}"
      options = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.pop : {}
      options.merge!(:layout => false)
      if collection = options.delete(:collection) then
        collection.inject([]) do |buffer, member|
          buffer << haml(:"#{template}", options.merge(:layout =>
          false, :locals => {template_array[-1].to_sym => member}))
        end.join("\n")
      else
        haml(:"#{template}", options)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Including this method, you may call `partial` in your `.haml` files, like
`= partial("partial_name")`

If you want to `render` a view in an other view syntax is
`= render(:haml,:'rel_path_to_view',:locals => {:optional => option})`

Notice the syntax differences between `rails` and `sinatra` regarding `render` method!

Comment: I truly don't understand why somebody would down vote an obviously outdated answer. At the time this was the right one. LoL doesn't matter :)

Comment: Since I see people are still linking to this answer, I took the code from the gist and made it into a gem, which [Lenary](https://github.com/lenary) (the author of the original gist) has also since contributed to. It has subsequent improvements and specs etc https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-partial.

Comment: I think it would be better to be down voted so that a better answer can be listed above it. Well, I know it actually shouldn't be done like that, but instead SO should have a feature to handle an outdated answer.

Answer (score 60):

You can just use Sinatra's haml function:

```
= haml :nav
```

Comment: In terms of code cleanliness, this trumps all the other solutions.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. You don't need any special code, it's built in!

Comment: you can getaway with using `= markdown :README` if you have it setup to properly use redcarpet

Comment: In case you're getting escaped HTML use:  
!= haml :nav

Answer (score 13):

Or you could just do this:

```
helpers do
  def partial(page, options={})
    haml page.to_sym, options.merge!(:layout => false)
  end
end
```

And include your partial with:

```
= partial( "something-rad" )
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I do it (more simply than @kfl62's answer, more feature-rich than @jm3's answer):

```ruby
module Partials
  def partial( page, variables={} )
    haml page.to_sym, {layout:false}, variables
  end
end
helpers Partials
```

Use it in your Haml file like:

```haml
%ul#comments
  - @comments.each do |comment|
    %li= partial :comment, comment:comment
```

Comment: I know this is *incredibly* old Phrogz, but something I wanted to point out... "haml page.to_sym, {layout:false}, variables" should probably be

"haml page.to_sym, {:layout => false}, variables"

Comment: @user766987 What you say works for old  1.8 and 1.9; my answer is using Ruby 1.9 syntax.