# Access Sinatra variable in partial

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm fairly new to Sinatra, and I'm trying to access data from a database from within a partial.

Here's an example of a partial that I want on a page:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <ul>
        <li> <%= article.articleName %> </li>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

It works fine if I just set up a route like

```
get '/articles' do
     @article = Articles.all
     erb :articles
end
```

and the /articles page with something like

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <article>
        <p> <%= article.articleName %> </p>
        <p> <%= article.articleBody %> </p>
    </article>
<% end %>
```

However, it doesn't seem like the above code works if I put it into a partial.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: I guess it's worth adding that when I run the app with the code in the partial, I get "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: More [info here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974878/rendering-a-partial-from-a-haml-file/3975168#3975168) Phrogz's answer is better then mine :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sinatra does not have built-in partials like Rails, but you can use ordinary templates as partials, as mentioned in: http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#partials

Example:

articles template:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>

<%= erb :'partials/_article', :layout => false, :locals => { :article => article } %>

<% end %>
```

partials/_article template:

```
Title <%= article.title %>

...
```

PS: set a path to partial from template root dir. This weird syntax `:'partials/_article'` is a Sinatra trick, it enables you to access template in subdir, this wouldn't work (I think): `:partials/_article` or `'partials/_article'`.

Answer (score 2):

Sinatra has no partial functionality built-in. So you have two options:

1. build your own partial handler like [here](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#implementation_of_rails_style_partials) or
2. use the partials.rb from [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#partials)